# How to get the Bootstrap dropdown selected li in span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the selected the html in dropdown. I'm using the Bootstrap dropdown how can I get this?

I need to show the selected value in span how can I do that?

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7055/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu status_change" role="menu" style="position: relative;">
    <li><a href="#">Waiting</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Approved</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Denied</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">Frozen</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Expired</a></li>
  </ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.status_change').click(function(){
    alert($(this).find('a').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register the handler to the li element

```
$('.status_change.dropdown-menu li').click(function () {
    alert($(this).find('a').html());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ay83nhxy/)

In your case `this` refers to the `ul` element in the handler so `$(this).find('a')` will return the content of the first li always

---

*Update*

Change your markup to

```
<span data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle status_change"><span class="status">Frozen</span><span class="caret fiveML"></span></span>
```

then

```
$('.status_change.dropdown-menu li').click(function () {
    $('.status_change.dropdown-toggle span.status').html($(this).find('a').html())
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ay83nhxy/3/)

Comment: @QuestionUser sorry which `li span`

Answer (score 0):

Its working

```
$('.status_change li').click(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7058/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$('.status_change li a').click(function(){
   var text1=$(this).text();
   var text2=$("span.status_change").html();
   $("span.status_change").html(text1+text2.substring(text2.indexOf("<span")));    
});
```

`.substring()` extracts the span element nested inside your span element where you want to insert the text.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7060/)

Comment: able to change the span class ?

Comment: @QuestionUser which span class? I think it works as you asked